# Advanced poll lists the same permissions as core poll module (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-permissions

The advanced poll module and core Poll module share the same permissions, which is according to this http://drupal.org/node/206757 unacceptable. In last paragraph there stands : "Your permission strings are arbitrary, but each must be unique among all installed modules. Otherwise, one occurrence of the name will take the permissions of the other."

Advanced poll and poll module share these permissions:
'vote on polls',
'cancel own vote',
'inspect all votes',
'show vote results'.

I'm having a big problem with voting on advanced poll and I wonder if this could be possibly the reason.
What happens if I just rename these permissions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Poll has not even reached beta so I'd not even think of using it.